# Read from file, but not every line

Tags: c, string, file, file-io

I am a beginner in programming, so I only know some "basic" codes and methods to do stuff, so when writing an answer, keep in mind that I might need a little bit more explanation than people usually need on this site. Thank you!

I have a homework assignment to do a text-based adventure game.
I MUST read the text from a file into the program to use.

At first I thought that I will write The 'Question' in one line,
And the next 3 lines after that line will be the lines having the 3 "choosing options".

With this method, I would have to create 4 arrays of strings (questions, ans1, ans2 and ans3) and then read every 4th line into every one of these strings (starting from a different line ofc.).

I hope you guys understand what I would like to do here. The question is, though, that, is that possible?

If yes, then how?

Currently I have this code, but this would read every line into the string if I put it in a cycle (for/while/etc.), but that is not good, cause I only need every 4th line into one array of strings.
Is that possible, to tell the program, to only read in every 4th line from the file?

My current code is:

```
char questions[40][200];
    FILE* fp;
    fp=fopen("text.txt", "r");
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=3; i++)
        {
            fgets(questions[i], 200, fp);
        }
    fclose(fp);
```

This would get the first 4 lines into the string which is not good. I would like the first 4 questions in my string in this case. How should I change my code to accomplish that?

Comment: have a counter, read and discard upto 3, store 4th and reset.

Comment: You will have to read every line regardless; you can decide to ignore a line after you've read it, but you'll still need to read it.  You'd have to impose more structure on the file to be able to skip around without reading the intermediate lines.  It's possible, but vastly harder than just reading and ignoring lines.

Comment: Why not read all at once: 1 question, 3 answer and start over.

Comment: @alk Do you mean something like this? Would this line of codes work for example? :

for (i=0; i<=3; i++)
        {
            fgets(questions[i], 200, fp);
            fgets(ans1[i], 200, fp);
            fgets(ans2[i], 200, fp);
            fgets(ans3[i], 200, fp);
        }

Comment: Depends on how all those variables are defined. Just give it a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to read all of the lines in your loop. Create additional arrays for each of your question options (e.g. an array to hold all "A" answers), then read them all in an interlaced format:

```
char questions[40][200];
char answersA[40][200];
char answersB[40][200];
char answersC[40][200];
/* ... */
for (i=0; i<=3 /* Or however many questions there are */; i++)
{
    fgets(questions[i], 200, fp); /* Read the question */
    /* Read the answers */
    fgets(answersA[i], 200, fp); /* Read the answer for option A */
    fgets(answersB[i], 200, fp); /* Read the answer for option B */
    fgets(answersC[i], 200, fp); /* Read the answer for option C */
}
/* ... */
```

*Addition*

Then, if you want to get the three answer options for a particular question `i`, just get `answersA[i]`, `answersB[i]`, and `answersC[i]`.

Comment: Ohh, I never thought that this would work!
This is easier than I thought it would be.
Thank you very much for your answer and help,
You get an upvote, and I will accept your answer as a solution as soon as I can!
Fast and helpful answer! Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the "D" option since you indicated in your question that you only have three answers. If you want a different number of answers, just read the correct number :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to use a struct to bring together what belongs together, namely question and answers:

```
#define QUESTION_SIZE (300)
#define ANSWER_SIZE (200)
#define NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS (42)
#define NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS (3)

struct QA
{
  char question[QUESTION_SIZE];      
  char answers[NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS][ANSWER_SIZE];
}

int main(void)
{
  struct QA qa[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS] = {0};

  FILE fp = .... /* open file here */

  size_t q;
  for (q = 0; q < NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; ++q)
  {
    fgets(qa[q].question, sizeof qa[q].question, fp);

    {
      size_t a;
      for (a = 0; a < NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS; ++a)
      {
        fgets(qa[q].answers[a], sizeof qa[q].answers[a], fp);
      }
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);

  ... /* do stuff */
```